# What determines the amount of tokens awarded after completing an explorable dungeon?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I just completed my first explorable dungeon and was happy to receive 30 tokens, until I realized the rest of the group got 60 and 55 tokens.

Do you miss out if you are dead at the wrong moment in a boss kill, or what determines the number of tokens received when completing the dungeon?

Comment: ArenaNet said they were going to [rebalance dungeon rewards in the next round of patches](https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/game/gw2/Dev-Tracker-Compilation-A-list-of-upcoming-fixes-and-changes/first), so answers to this question might be outdated pretty quickly.

Comment: This is a valid question in general, but in your specific case, however, you're running into a **bug** where the "really fast dungeon run diminishing returns" kick in for you when they should not be. ANet has already commented on this, as Dalshim mentions below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the recent update, each player gets awarded an extra 40 tokens on top of the usual 20 for each dungeon route he takes in a day (doing three times the same dungeon with the three different routes will give you 180 tokens).

However, update had bugs. Some players were considered to exploit the dungeon and get rewarded only 15 tokens for their first dungeon (then 6), and others only 30. (Behaviour has been corrected since the 2nd of October)

There have been rumors that these players would get their tokens back in a future update, but only if they have reported the bug (these are rumors). It is recommended to send bug reports when this happens and you are still in the dungeon (type "/bug" in the chat).

I personally only receive 15 tokens on my first dungeon and report the bug each time, in case the update would give me the missing one back.

Comment: This would make sense, except I've have both cases happen to me. I've run through Caudecus's Manor six times to far, got 60 tokens for three of the runs and 45 tokens for the other three.

Comment: @Confuzzledmaniac : It also could be there isn't only one bug or it depends on the server you are running on during the dungeon. I'm not the developer so can't assure anything, but that is what the rumors have been saying.

Answer (score 4):

Changes from September 25th patch:

"ArenaNet said that dungeons reward 20 tokens for completion and now reward an additional 40 tokens the first time they are completed each day."

"Dungeon tokens are now rewarded at the end of an explorable chain."

[Source](http://guildwars2pc.com/2012/guild-wars-2-daily-news-dungeons-now-reward-40-more-tokens-but-theres-a-catch/)

Note: There have been various players debating the validity of this information. Many players within the same group have received a varying amount of tokens. As such, there may be other factors involved, or the system may be temporarily bugged.

(Before the patch, dungeon bosses provided tokens, and additional tokens were provided upon the completion of the dungeon)